# SocketIO: Emitting within Flask @app.route?

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

is it possible to use socketio.emit from within a flask route?

Here is my server code:

```
application = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
socketio = SocketIO(application, cors_allowed_origins="*", logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@application.route('/event', methods=['POST'])
def handle_event():
    ...
    ... do stuff
    ...
    socketio.emit('new_message', {'js_code': js_code}, namespace='/messages')
    return jsonify(result), 200
```

Here is my client code:

```
var socket = io('https://website/messages', {transports: ['websocket']});
    
socket.on('new_message', function(data) { 
        console.log('message socket event received client-side')
    });
```

I receive it in the console server-side, but I don't receive it client-side:

```
emitting event "new_message" to all [/messages]
```

Tested emitting the new_message within `@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/messages')` and it worked just fine, so it seems to be only a problem with flask routes

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

also extra context: the /event flask route is not accessible on the website for typical user browsing, it is used by a different program to send data there

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. My guess is that there are no connected clients at the time the `/event` route was invoked. If there were any, you would see additional lines after `emitting event` in the log, one per connected client.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Hi Miguel, what confuses me is io.on('connect') sends the message so I figured the client would be connected; will add an io.on('disconnect') and see if anything prints. Thanks for the reply!